# Angular 12: Event emitter is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, typescript4.0

I am learning Angular (version 12.0.1, TypeScript 4.3.4) and cannot figure out why this event emitter is undefined. Any ideas?

The error message I get: ERROR TypeError: this.gameClick is undefined

.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.scss']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  gameInterval: number = 0;
  score: number = 0;

  @Output() gameClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<{ clicks: number }>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  emitEvent() {
    this.gameClick.emit({ clicks: this.score });
    this.score++;
  }

  startGame() {
    this.gameInterval = setInterval(this.emitEvent, 1000);
  }

  stopGame() {
    clearInterval(this.gameInterval);
  }
}
```

html file:

```
<div class="controls">
  <button
    class="btn-game"
    (click)="startGame()"
    >Start game</button>
  <button
    class="btn-game"
    (click)="stopGame()"
    >Stop game</button>
</div>
```

Comment: To preserve the meaning of `this` in the callback, it must either be an arrow function: `setInterval(() => this.emitEvent(), 1000)` or use `bind()`: `setInterval(this.emitEvent.bind(this), 1000);` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this function:

```
emitEvent() {
    this.gameClick.emit({ clicks: this.score });
    this.score++;
}
```

to

```
emitEvent = (): void => {
    this.gameClick.emit({ clicks: this.score });
    this.score++;
}
```